# Understanding NTP stratum

Tags: ntp

1. In Linux (RHEL 7+) how can I get the stratum value of an NTP server I had specified to use in `/etc/chrony.conf` ?
2. For the [List of Top Public Time Servers](https://gist.github.com/mutin-sa/eea1c396b1e610a2da1e5550d94b0453) if that is correct, some are identified as stratum 1, but others like `time.windows.com` and `time.nist.gov` don't specify a stratum level.
3. [The NTP Stratum Model](https://safran-navigation-timing.com/manuals/SS/Content/_Global/Topics/NTP/NTP_Stratums.htm) says:

   > Stratum 0 means a device is directly connected to e.g., a GPS antenna. Stratum 0 devices cannot distribute time over a network directly, though, hence they must be linked to a Stratum 1 time server that will distribute time to Stratum 2 servers or clients, and so on. The higher the Stratum number, the more the timing accuracy and stability degrades.

I am looking at getting a Time Machine's "GPS NTP Network Time Server (TM1000A)"][3](https://timemachinescorp.com/product/gps-time-server-tm1000a/) TimeMachines TM1000A time server - it has a GPS antenna and serves out time onto a network per its description.

What *Stratum* would this thing be?  Per the NTP Stratum definition/model, can anyone actually be a stratum-0 or is 0 the one time source from which all is derived from and if so who/where is that exactly?  Or would that be *stratum -1* and stratum 0 is simply the signal coming from GPS satellites?  But then where do the GPS satellites get their time from?

Comment: Stratum 0 devices get their time from atomic clocks in the GPS satellites, run by government scientists. They give time ONLY to Stratum 1 devices. The documentation you refer to says it provides Stratum 1 services,. It probably has an intrrnal Stratum 0 thst listens to GPS

Comment: Actually given the little effort in researching and the multiple questions being asked, I wonder whether the only purpose of this question is product promotion. Specifically see answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/762205/320598

Comment: time.windows.com is currently declaring stratum 3, and time.nist.gov is declares itself as stratum 1

Answer (score 0):

When I read the product link today, it said:

> The TM1000A is a simple NTP GPS network time server. It is a cost-effective solution that makes Stratum 1 time synchronization possible across your network.

So you did not read about **Stratum 1** before asking the question?

Anyway:
"stratum" is a dynamic software concept, not a static hardware concept.

Per definition *reference clocks* are assigned a stratum value of **0**, and any "consumer" of a time source has a stratum one level higher than the stratum of the selected time source.

See also:

- [Clock strata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol#Clock_strata) in Wikipedia's article on the Network Time Protocol
- [5.1.1.5 What is a stratum 1 Server?](https://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/ntp-s-algo/#5115-what-is-a-stratum-1-server) within *How does it work? - NTP: Network Time Protocol* of the NTP FAQ.